# Azure Data Factory - delete data from a MongoDb (Atlas) Collection

Tags: azure-data-factory, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to use Azure Data Factory (V2) to copy data to a MongoDb database on Atlas, using the [MongoDB Atlas connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mongodb-atlas) but I have an issue.

I want to do an Upsert but the data I want to copy has no primary key, and as the documentation says:

> Note: Data Factory automatically generates an _id for a document if an
> _id isn't specified either in the original document or by column mapping. This means that you must ensure that, for upsert to work as
> expected, your document has an ID.

This means the first load works fine, but then subsequent loads just insert more data rather than replacing current records.

I also can't find anything native to Data Factory that would allow me to do a delete on the target collection before running the Copy step.

My fallback will be to create a small Function to delete the data in the target collection before inserting fresh, as below.  A full wipe and replace.  But before doing that I wondered if anyone had tried something similar before and could suggest something within Data Factory that I have missed that would meet my needs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per the [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/documents/delete/), You cannot delete multiple documents at once from the MongoDB Atlas. As an alternative, you can use the `db.collection.deleteMany()` method in the embedded MongoDB Shell to delete multiple documents in a single operation.

It has been recommended to use Mongo Shell to delete via query. To delete all documents from a collection, pass an empty filter document {} to the `db.collection.deleteMany()` method.

Eg: `db.movies.deleteMany({})`

Comment: Thanks @UtkarshPal-MT, but the main issue here is that the Azure Data Factory connector doesn't seem to allow for running any commands, or even dropping a collection which is what I'd normally do if I wanted to delete all the data.

Comment: In ADF we do not have specific activity, but you can write you own powershell script and execute it using Custom activity.